# Can we write $\frac{1}{2}\frac{-y}{\sqrt{-xy}}$ as $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{-y}}{\sqrt{x}}$ if $x$ and $y$ have different signs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|}$ and consider the case where $x$ and $y$ have different signs.

Then $f(x,y)=\sqrt{-xy}$ and

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{-y}{\sqrt{-xy}}\tag{1}$$

Are we permitted to write any of the following $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{-y}}{\sqrt{x}}\tag{2}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{-\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{-x}}\tag{3}$$

In (2), both radicands are negative if $x<0$ and both are positive if $x>0$.

In (3), both radicands are negative if $x>0$, and both are positive if $x<0$.

On the other hand, I am not sure what property of numbers precludes the operations that led to (2) or (3).

For example in the case of (2), I believe the operations were to write $\sqrt{-xy}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{-y}$ and then to do

$$\frac{(-y)^1}{(-y)^{1/2}}=(-y)^{1-1/2}=(-y)^{1/2}$$

Comment: The simplification worked only if x was positive and y negative.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we write $\frac{1}{2}\frac{-y}{\sqrt{-xy}}$ as $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{-y}}{\sqrt{x}}$ if $x$ and $y$ have different signs?

The counterexample $(x,y)=(-1,1)$ shows that $$\frac{1}{2}\frac{-y}{\sqrt{-xy}}\not\equiv\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{-y}}{\sqrt{x}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{-y}{\sqrt{-xy}}$$

requires $-xy >0$, then what is true in general is that

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{-y}{\sqrt{-xy}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{-y}{\sqrt{-xy}}\frac{\sqrt{-xy}}{\sqrt{-xy}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{-y\sqrt{-xy}}{-xy}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{-xy}}{x}$$